# drupal_form_submit() does not update(edit) the node?

Tags: 7, forms

$fs has following data

```
 $fs = Array
(
    [values] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [target_id] => val_1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_download_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => 1
                )

            [field_download_nid_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [target_id] => Downloaded_48840
                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_status_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => 7
                )

            [field_view_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => 1
                )

            [field_view_nid_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [target_id] => Viewed_48840
                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_rt] => Array
                (
                    [und] => 0
                )

            [field_date_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => Array
                                        (
                                            [date] => 11/19/1927
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_date_2] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => Array
                                        (
                                            [date] => 17/08/2011
                                            [time] => 20:04
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_date_2] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => Array
                                        (
                                            [date] => 18/08/2011
                                            [time] => 08:49
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [field_text_field_1] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 
text is displayed here 
                                )

                        )

                )
            [nid] => 48840
            [vid] => 48840
            [uid] => 1
            [op] => Report stamp
        )

    [triggering_element] => Array
        (
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

The [drupal_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) is called when submit button is clicked on a form(which is not abc_node_form).
`drupal_form_submit('abc_node_form', $fs, $node );`
**abc_node_form** : form_id of content type abc .
**$fs** : has all the values extracted from the $node.
**$node** : form_state of the form which has all the values for which the content_type abc needs to be updated.
Also I have checked for form_get_errors(), I dont get any errors but the form node does not get updated.;

Comment: Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45752/what-is-the-best-choice-to-create-a-node-through-code

Comment: I have added it in same manner but it still does not upadate the node. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: make sure you are inlcuding module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

Comment: yes I have included it but still it does not updated whereas node_save() updates the node if used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @znerol

Additionally one needs to ensure that $fs['values']['op'] is set to the value of the **submit button on the target form**. In this example I think it should be 
`$fs['values']['op'] = t('Save');`

this solved the problem and node is being updated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure about the parameters you are using

```
 drupal_form_submit('abc_node_form', $fs, $node );
```

- '`abc_node_form`'- is the appropriate form id.
- `$fs` - current state of 
  the form. Most important is the $form_state['values'] collection .
- `$node` - is the old node object, that you will find in $form_state['node'],if using default node creation form.

I am not sure how you are getting $node value,here is small snippet which can be helpful to build $node

```
  // Before drupal_form_submit()
  $node = node_load($fs['nid']);
  $fs['node'] = $node;
  drupal_form_submit('abc_node_form', $fs, $node );
```

Comment: Additionally one needs to ensure that `$fs['values']['op']` is set to the value of the submit button on the target form. In this example I think it should be `$fs['values']['op'] = t('Save');`

Comment: `$fs = array()` .What all values should $fs have ? Should it have nid,vid,revision etc also along with fs['values']

Answer (score 1):

this was how i submitted an existing node using drupal_form_submit:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$fs['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = drupal_build_form('mytype_node_form', $fs);
$fs['node'] = $node;
$fs['values']['op'] = t('Save');
drupal_form_submit('mytype_node_form', $fs, $node);
```